# How to get the start and end position of selected text from Python Tkinter Text widget

Tags: tkinter, position, cursor, selection

I want to get the start and end position of selected text in a Tkinter Text widget. If no text is selected, it should use the position of the cursor for both start and end positions.

It also appears that if the selection starts at "1.0" it returns an error.

I have code that works, but I was wondering whether there is a simpler way to do the same thing:

```
from tkinter import *

# Objective:
# Get position of start and end of selection in a tkinter text widget
# Use SEL_FIRST and SEL_LAST (or "sel.first" and "sel.last")
# If no text is selected, SEL_FIRST and SEL_LAST will return an error
# Also, if the selection starts at "1.0", SEL_FIRST will return an error

# Generate text
testText = ""
for r in range(8):
    testText += f'{r+1}12345678\n'

def get_info_of_selection():
   
    # Boolean variables for selection
    no_selection = False    # If True --> no text is selected
    start_found = False     # If True --> start of selection was found

    # CURSOR: determine index and position
    index_cursor = myTextWidget.index(INSERT)   # Can also use "insert"
    if index_cursor == "1.0":
        position_cursor = 0
        # If the cursur is at the beginning, the start of the selection will also be there
        start_found = True
        index_start = index_cursor
        position_start = position_cursor
    else:
        position_cursor = myTextWidget.count("1.0", index_cursor)[0]

    # END OF SELECTION: Determine index and position
    try:
        index_end = myTextWidget.index(SEL_LAST)   # Can also use "sel.last" instead of "SEL_LAST"
        position_end = myTextWidget.count("1.0", SEL_LAST)[0]
    except:
        # No text is selected --> use the index and position of the cursor
        index_end = index_cursor
        position_end = position_cursor
        # Also, set no_selection to True
        no_selection = True

    # START OF SELECTION: determine index and position
    if not start_found:
        if no_selection:
            # If no text is selected --> use the index and position of the cursor
            index_start = index_cursor
            position_start = position_cursor
        else:
            try:
                index_start = myTextWidget.index(SEL_FIRST)   # Can also use "sel.first" instead of "SEL_FIRST"
                position_start = myTextWidget.count("1.0", SEL_FIRST)[0]
            except:
                index_start = "1.0"
                position_start = 0

    # Update label with information
    msg = f'Cursor index | position = {index_cursor} | {position_cursor}\nStart index | position = {index_start} | {position_start}\nEnd index | position = {index_end} | {position_end}'
    myLabel.config(text = msg)
    


root = Tk()

myButton = Button(root, text="Get start and end position of selection/cursor", command=get_info_of_selection)
myButton.pack(pady=10, ipady=5)

myTextWidget = Text(root)
myTextWidget.pack(fill=X)
myTextWidget.insert('insert', testText)

myLabel = Label(root, text="")
myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current code? If there is an error please give us the error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You have overcomplicated the problem significantly. You get the index of the start and end of the selection with the indexes `"sel.first"` and `"sel.last"`. You can use them in a try/except block so that if there isn't a selection you can set the values to the index of `"insert"`:

```
def get_info_of_selection():
    try:
        index_start = myTextWidget.index("sel.first")
        index_end = myTextWidget.index("sel.last")
    except TclError:
        index_start = index_end = myTextWidget.index("insert")

    msg = f"start: {index_start}\nend: {index_end}"
    myLabel.config(text = msg)
```